# Nyquist's theorem misunderstanding

Tags: signal-processing, homework

I have been assigned the following question:

[image]

From what I understood of Nyquist's theorem for a signal that contains power over a range of frequencies that does not include 0 Hz i.e. over a known bandwidth B with fmin > 0. The minimum sample rate is twice the bandwidth for the convolution images to not overlap.

In this case the bandwidth is 4 MHz and so it seems as though all the frequencies suggested by the question: 100 MHz, 150 MHz and 200 MHz are wouldn't result in information loss.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't have information between 0 to 100 MHz, and the 100 to 200 MHz gets folded/aliased back to 0..100 MHz range, what information would get lost when sampled at 200 MHz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in noting that the crux of this question is the fact that fmin > 0. After all, if fmin = 0 then this reduces to the most canonical application of Nyquist's Theorem and all three sample rates (100 MHz, 150 MHz, and 200 MHz) would cause aliasing because they are less than twice the maximum frequency in the spectrum, as shown in the diagram below:

[image]

For fmin > 0, there may be some sample rates less than 2fmax where the signal may still be recovered, simply because the alias bands will fall at different frequencies than the intended signal band.

The problem text suggests a good way to find which sample rates will work: simply draw the convolution images and see if they overlap.

For example, a sample rate of 150 MHz will surely cause aliasing because 149 MHz and -151 MHz will end up right on top of each other. By drawing it out, you should be able to find whether the other sample frequencies work. Hope this helps!